# Eclipse Java runtime classpath and different library versions

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

Suppose there are 2 (non-Maven, legacy) projects in Eclipse.

- A -> *depends on* B and lib-2.0.jar
- B -> *depends on* lib-1.0.jar

When we run a HelloWorld.java from project A, the runtime classpath is 
**A\classes;A\lib\lib-2.0.jar;B\classes;B\lib\lib-1.0.jar**

(even though library lib-1.0.jar is not marked as 'Exported' on Java build path settings of project B). Probably that checkbox has influence just on compile-time classpath, not on the runtime one.

We need to exclude lib-1.0.jar PERMANENTLY for the whole project A (since -2.0 contains incompatible changes, and presence of both lib-1.0.jar & lib-2.0.jar in the runtime classpath causes bad consequences).

The desired classpath would be: **A\classes;A\lib\lib-2.0.jar;B\classes**.

How can this be achieved globally for the whole project?

I found a possibility to specify a concrete launch configuration with a custom runtime classpath.
But this way to solve the problem is hard-to-support:
- need to specify such launch config for every class we need to be runnable in project A
- need to modify it as soon as new libraries are added.

Thank you for your ideas!

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you need but you can right click on project A, Build Path -> Configure Build Path and in the Projects tab add your project B, now whenever you'll add something to B, it will be 'visible' in A.

Comment: The problem is with transitive libraries that should be excluded

Comment: define an access rule in a project tab and exclude library folder from project B

Comment: that's a nice suggestion about access rule, but it looks like it has influence just in compilation. The runtime classpath still has both libraries.